# How to deal with ContentNotFoundError when using wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: qt, command-line, wkhtmltopdf, download, wkhtmltoimage

Can someone tell me how to resolve following issues?

1. wkhtmltopdf don't have option to pass proxy info (-p or --proxy) unlike in previous versions and its not using system $http_proxy and $https_proxy env variable too.
2. wkhtmltopdf not working with HTTPS/SSL even though i set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for libssl.so and libcrypto.so

   ```
   [deploy@localhost ~]$ wkhtmltopdf https://www.google.co.in google.pdf
   loaded the Generic plugin 
   Loading page (1/2)
   Error: Failed loading page https://www.google.co.in (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
   Exit with code 1 due to network error: UnknownNetworkError
   ```

   and

   ```
   [deploy@localhost ~]$ wkhtmltoimage https://www.google.co.in sample.jpg
   loaded the Generic plugin 
   Loading page (1/2)
   Error: Failed loading page https://www.google.co.in (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
   Exit with code 1 due to network error: UnknownNetworkError
   ```
3. wkhtmltopdf working partially with HTTP. The output pdf files missing some content/background/positions.

   ```
   [deploy@localhost ~]$ wkhtmltopdf http://localhost:8880/ sample.pdf
   loaded the Generic plugin 
   Loading page (1/2)
   Printing pages (2/2)                                               
   Done                                                           
   Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError

   [deploy@localhost ~]$ wkhtmltoimage http://localhost:8880/ sample.jpg
   loaded the Generic plugin 
   Loading page (1/2)
   Rendering (2/2)                                                    
   Done                                                               
   Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError
   ```

Note: Im using wkhtmltopdf-0.12.1-1.fc20.x86_64 and qt-4.8.6-10.fc20.x86_64

Comment: These really sound like bugs that would be best answered by ashkulz in the github issue tracker, I think your best luck will be asking there.

Comment: See: [Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError #2051](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2051)

Comment: I was receiving similar error and removed @font-face from css and problem disappeared.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `wkhtmltopdf` doesn't handle downloading of complex websites, because it's uses Qt/QtWebKit library which seems to have some issues.

One problem is that `wkhtmltopdf` doesn't support relative addresses (GitHub: [#1634](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1634), [#1886](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1886), [#2359](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2359), [QTBUG-46240](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46240)) such as:

```
<img src="/images/filetypes/txt.png">
<script src="//cdn.optimizely.com/js/653710485.js">
```

and it loads them as local. One solution which I've found to this is the correcting html file in-place by `ex` in-place editor:

```bsh
ex -V1 page.html <<-EOF
  %s,'//,'http://,ge 
  %s,"//,"http://,ge 
  %s,'/,'http://www.example.com/,ge
  %s,"/,"http://www.example.com/,ge
  wq " Update changes and quit.
EOF
```

However it won't work for files which have these type of URLs on the remote.

Another problem is that it doesn't handle missing resources. You can try to specify `--load-error-handling ignore`, but in most cases it doesn't work (see [#2051](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2051)), so this is still outstanding. Workaround is to simply remove these invalid resources, before conversion.

Alternatively to `wkhtmltopdf`, you can use either `htmldoc`, [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) with some additional script, for example using [rasterize.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js):

```
phantomjs rasterize.js http://example.com/
```

or [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) (HTML to PDF converter for PHP, you can install by composer) with sample code below:

```
<?php
// somewhere early in your project's loading, require the Composer autoloader
// see: http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md
$HOMEDIR = "/Users/foo";
require $HOMEDIR . '/.composer/vendor/autoload.php';

// disable DOMPDF's internal autoloader if you are using Composer
define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD', FALSE);
define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE', TRUE);

// include DOMPDF's default configuration
require_once $HOMEDIR . '/.composer/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';

$htmlString = file_get_contents("https://example.com/foo.pdf");

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($htmlString);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

Comment: It went the same way you mentioned here, I too got to know relative resource paths, broken links etc after little more work on wkhtmltopdf. I fixed my problem with phantomjs scripts.

Answer (score 2):

my problem was solved removing @font-face from css.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before. and solve that like below.

[image: wkhtmltopdf]

In the above example i had some "src" files and "url"s  that they refer to the static directory but the static directory didn't exist so wkhtmltopdf thrown me that error. for example:

src: url("file:///home/ehsan/Projects/Example/main/sib/**static**/WebYekan.eot");

and one more important thing i have to say is all the file paths in html files have to be an absolute path. do not use relative path at all.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot but could not find but finally found over here. I was using (./name) but that created the contentnotfound error.

But finally used the complete address and got the desired result

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow what you are suggesting as an answer. Maybe a code example of your solution?